# Turning colorized comic-art into uncolorized monochrome (line-art-inks-only B&W), not just very-light-grayscale

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, 2d, 2d-graphics, bitmap-graphics

I'm trying to figure out how to go about removing the "colorization" of comic/cartoon/manga/etc drawn-art inputs where the black-ink strokes ("the line-art") are to be retained against (near-perfectly-)white "background" — but also in a smooth non-jagged manner so there'll be some retaining/graying of the "fade tones" from the ink-blacks to the background (formerly colored, now white).

(Note: I'm trying to go here *[without](https://aaronhertzmann.com/2020/04/19/lines-as-edges.html#problem-5-edge-detection-is-not-a-line-drawing-algorithm) edge-detection or vector-ization or binarization algos*, for "merely" a smoother alternative to any & all always-jaggy B/W thresholding (binarization) approaches you'll ever find.)

This colorized input, for example, sports quite dark colorization tones that would still have to turn (near-)`#FF` for the removing-colorization-but-preserving-the-black-inks use case — despite (in grayscale) being quite close to the original-black-inks-to-be-fully-preserved in the (seemingly ca.) `#00..#36` range.

[image]

The problem is likely simplified (though that's just assumption on my part, not a necessary requirement) by first generating a light-greyscale (max-decomposition ie. `gray=max(r,g,b)`) version to work with:

[image]

Now any given hard-coded threshold cutoff value `t` (for turning all-grays-above-`t` into `#FF`, keeping all-below-`t` as they are) will not "work" to produce a smooth outcome, to wit for `t=#36`:

[image]

**No matter** one's choice of cutoff threshold `t`, the result will naturally **always** be jaggy and impoverished (just in different places), with some lines too-severely-thickened, others too harshly thinned or lost, plus dither noise. This goes for hard-coded thresholds or auto-thresholding-computed ones (unless there's one I haven't encountered yet that's especially geared to this scenario — most of them are for lo-fi text-scans or photographs).

What's really needed at these low resolutions is to fade as smoothly into white from the line-blacks as they originally fade into colorization (or grayscaled, into grays).

I guess that there should be **either** some near-perfectly-suited *Curve* (`some 0..1 -> another 0..1` I haven't yet found) that would solve this "good enough" (for the human visual perception), **or** perhaps some other papers/algos/research/gfx-techniques tackling this very use-case (albeit in jargon I wouldn't know to include in searches)... thanks for any ideas and pointers!

Comment: I wonder whether the first step of creating a grayscale image is leading you down a suboptimal path. I'd be tempted to try doing a color separation first, processing the redscale, greenscale, and bluescale images separately, and then merging the results. If that doesn't help, I'd probably start looking for a matrix blur filter or edge detector that can consider more local context than the simple threshold operation does.

Comment: Use a halftoning algorithm such as Floyd-Steinberg or direct binary search. You can also try more advanced algorithms such as the stippling here (see the figures): https://arxiv.org/abs/2206.07798

Comment: Thanks @lightxbulb — I should clarify that all "colorization" (aside from the black-ink-strokes aka "outlines") is not to be re-expressed into black-dot arrangements (stippling / half-toning) but "removed wholly" (turned `#ffffff` except for the "subpixel-ish" fade-to-black grey tones for retaining a non-jagged smoothness)

Comment: Thanks @luserdroog I'm tempted to experiment in that color-sep direction, but I can't quite intuit what I'd do with each separate channel before the final merge?

(Btw. I did one experiment where I determine a pixel's "colorness / non-gray-ness" via the deltas between channels. Idea being, the more "colorish" a pixel, the more it turns into white. Somehow it ended up as a perfectly fine greyscale rather than the truly (perceptually) inks-only non-colorized black-white monochrome that I'm seeking here to "restore" even for fairly lo-res (HD/FHD rather than 4K so to speak) inputs...)

Comment: Then I am not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve or why you call it colorization. Colorization typically means producing a color image from a greyscale one. "I'm trying to go here" - I guess my question is where is "there"? What do you want to get as a result?

Comment: @lightxbulb sorry for any unclear phrasings prior, it's all about "removing the colorization in comic-art images" where the black-ink strokes are to be retained against (near-perfectly-)white "background" --- but also in a smooth non-jagged manner so there'll be some gray tones in the fade from the ink-blacks to the background (formerly colored, now white). Hence binary thresholding is out...

Comment: You might want to look into the distance transform here is a paper on the subject  https://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~tants/jfa/i3d06.pdf and here is an implementation https://www.shadertoy.com/view/4syGWK